# How to start process at foreground saving it's pid to a file?

Tags: bash, process

Is there a way to save pid while starting a process? The script should not return to a command line, until started process finishes. And the possibility to end process by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should be kept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
command &
echo $! > file
fg > /dev/null
```

If there's no job control, first turn on monitor mode with

```
set -m
```

More about monitor mode here: [Turning off the monitor mode in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325448/turning-off-the-monitor-mode-in-bash).